# Getting an exception ClassCastException java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long while using Optional (Java 8) but not otherwise

Tags: java, java-8, casting, type-conversion, option-type

I have a function that returns long. A CastClassException is thrown if I use Optional but is not thrown other wise. Look at the below code -

```
public static Object returnNull() {
    return null;
}

public static long getLong(){
    return (long) Optional.ofNullable(returnNull()).orElse(0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getLong());
}
```

If I run the above code I get this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

So from the above it looks like the orElse(0) is creating an Integer object with value 0 but is not able to case it to long (primitive) and this throws the error (which is for Long object).

But, if I do this without Optional it doesn't give the error. Something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 0;
        long l = (long) i;
        System.out.println(l);
}
```

The above gives no error and 0 is printed.
I know I can solve the issue with Optional by doing
`.orElse(0L)`

But I'm not looking for solution to get rid of this error instead I'm looking to understand why does the above error occur while using Optional and doesn't occur otherwise.

Comment: `Integer x = 5; Long y = x;` will not be compiled for the same reason.

Comment: @Eugene I understand that it creates an Optional<Integer> but what if I want to return a long 0? It complains that it cannot convert Integer to Long. But if I do .orElse(0L) in that case it would create Optional<Long> which also should complain about casting but it doesn't

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes if we create a Long object definitely. But not if we type cast it to primitive long as mentioned above in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why does the error occur?

You can cast a primitive `int` implicitly to a primitive `long`.

You cannot cast an `Integer` object to a `Long` object. `Integer` is not a subclass of `Long` (both are subclasses of `Number`). Were you trying to do that? `orElse()` is declared to take the generic type `T` as argument, so an object. So Java autoboxes your `0` to an `Integer`. Because `0` is an `int`. This also explains why `0L` worked: now Java autoboxes to a `Long`. This is where autoboxing can make things unclear.

### Can we avoid the L in 0L?

It’s a little bit wordy, but I consider it clean:

```
public static long getLong(){
    return Optional.ofNullable(returnNull())
            .stream()
            .map(obj -> (Long) obj)
            .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

Frankly I would go with the `0L` that you already had. One reason why my attempt gets wordy is that `Optional` hasn’t got a `mapToLong` method, so I convert the `Optional` to a stream (of 0 or 1 element) and back to an `OptionalLong`. And why it works is that `OptionalLong.orElse()` takes a primitive `long` as argument, so here Java casts my primitive `int`, 0, to a `long`.

Here’s another working variant:

```
public static long getLong(){
    return ((Number) Optional.ofNullable(returnNull()).orElse(0)).longValue();
}
```

I am exploiting that `Long` and `Integer` are both`NUmber` and that the `longValue` method is declared in the `Number` superclass.

Answer (score 0):

These are different things that you show. Basically a small refactor makes things easier to grasp, I guess:

```
public static long getLong(){
    Object opt = Optional.ofNullable(returnNull()).orElse(0);
    return (long) opt;
}
```

As such, your other example should really be written as (and it will fail with the same Exception) :

```
    Integer i = 0;
    Object obj = i;
    long l = (long) obj;
```

To achieve what you want:

```
public static long getLong(){
    return (long) (int)Optional.ofNullable(returnNull()).orElse(0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you also explain the answer conceptually whether why does it fail/pass in corresponding situations? I'm not able to understand this conceptually to be honest. @Eugene

Comment: In case the method returning an `Object` in fact did return a `Long` object, your last solution may loose information.

Comment: @OleV.V. of course you will lose information, but that is something for OP to think about.

Comment: @MananSatra you do not need to understand if "conceptually", [there is an entire chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html) that explains what and how these conversions happen. To a somehow wrong degree, when the compiler sees `Object obj = I;` it first boxes `i` and then tries to cast. This `long l = (long) I;` on the other hand is _widening_ `i` to `long`. Again, the JLS chapter has the exact rules (which is an exercise left to you)